# UIButton inside UIContainerView triggered in ParentView

Tags: ios, swift, containers

In my containerView I placed 2 Buttons (check and cross)
I would like to access them from my ParentViewController.
The Container also got a gestureRecognizer on it.

I got the outlets going and the buttons perusable, but nothing seems to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you're doing without code to examine.

Comment: Try to addTarget for parent view controller.

Comment: What do you mean by addTarget ? How do I do this?

Comment: @PhillipMills There is no actual code to execute. Just trying something like print("hello") But my Button is inside a Container Viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer myself by now:

Made two outlets of the buttons + added the Target after that

```
    checkButton.addTarget(singleModeVC(), action: "checkButton_click:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    closeButton.addTarget(singleModeVC(), action: "closeButton_click:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```